# Custom Domain for Wordpress on GAE PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I would like to use a custom domain for my Wordress install on Google App Engine PHP Beta.
The main problem is that the WP installs run under a special sub-domain - not the general application one.

```
wp-dot-YOUR-APP-ID.appspot.com
```

is there a workaround?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: And there's a $50 credit right now to offset the cost of Google Apps: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM/XPJYq1HUgusJ

Comment: Thanks, but that covers only mapping YOUR-APP-ID.mycustomdomain.com to YOUR-APP-ID.appspot.com - I cannot just add wp-dot- to it to make it work. Or do I miss something

Comment: why are you running wordpress as a version of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine allows you to run multiple deployments of an application at the same time. These are differentiated using 'versions'. When you deploy an application, you specify the version that you are deploying in the `app.yaml` file. If you change the version to something else, then rather than overriding the existing copy of your app deployed under that version, a new copy of app will be deployed under the new version.

Each version is addressable by a unique URL of the form `<version name>-dot-<app name>.appspot.com`. `<version name>.<app name>.appspot.com` also works if you don't need SSL.

In addition, a specific version served from `<app name>.appspot.com` - this is called the default version. You can change which version is the default from the Versions tab in the App Engine admin console at http://appengine.google.com/.

Now, to your problem - your app is deployed under the version `wp`, which is why you can access it from that URL. If you want to access it from `YOUR-APP-ID.appspot.com` then you'll need to make it the default.

When setting up a custom domain, you need to map your app engine app to a subdomain. For example you might map `myapp` to the subdomain, `www`, meaning `myapp.appspot.com` is accessible from `www.mydomain.com`. This will serve the default version of `myapp`, as you'd expect.

With versions, these are extended, so `wp-dot-myapp.appspot.com` is accessible from `wp.www.appspot.com`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you - I followed the getting started instructions on the develoeprs website and they didn't explain the versions/default versions etc. Now I set the default version and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you can have your App serve off pretty much any sub-submain of your custom domain including serving off of multiple sub-domains at the same time.